# Change boolean field via click link

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm use images to represent state of boolean field (like openeye.png, closeeye.png). If I click image, state is changing, and page must refresh with another image. There are some views which use this. There is a code:

**template - this may be moviegrid.html, movielist.html, etc**

```
{% if movi.seen %}    {# movi.seen is a boolean field #}
    <div id="seen">
        <a href="{% url views.changeseen movi.tmdb_id %}">
             <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}seen.gif">
        </a>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div id="seen">
        <a href="{% url views.changeseen movi.tmdb_id %}">
             <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}not_seen.gif" >
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**views.changeseen**

```
def changeseen(request, id):
    mov=Movi.objects.get(tmdb_id=id)
    mov.seen=not mov.seen
    mov.save()
    return redirect('??????')
```

QUESTION: How do I return to the parent page from `changeseen`? And if there is more elegant way to change bool value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be elegant, you could call the `changeseen` view thought an AJAX `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* use the HTTP referrer (in the HTTP Referer field, accessible via `req.META['HTTP_REFERER']`) there is no guarantee that this will be set or even valid. I would suggest that you pass some information about the current page to changeseen, in the URL:

```
{% if movi.seen %}    {# movi.seen is a boolean field #}
<div id="seen">
    <a href="{% url views.changeseen movi.tmdb_id %}?return_to={{ request.get_full_path }}">
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}seen.gif">
    </a>
</div>
{% else %}
<div id="seen">
    <a href="{% url views.changeseen movi.tmdb_id %}?return_to={{ request.get_full_path }}">
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}not_seen.gif" >
    </a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

You should validate return_to before you actually redirect the user to it, and if it doesn't seem to make sense (like redirecting to a logout URL, or even offsite) then you should just redirect them to a default location, like the main movie page.